# Reading three or more separate values in one line in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading two separate values in one line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390264/reading-two-separate-values-in-one-line-in-python)

So here's my program so far:

```
import turtle
turtle.showturtle()
def turtle_commands():
    while True :
          n = 0
          instructions = input().split()
          i = instructions[0]
          if len(instructions) > 1:
              n = int(instructions[1])
              if i == 'forward' :
                  turtle.forward(n)
              elif i == 'backward' :
                  turtle.backward(n)
              elif i == 'left' :
                  turtle.left(n)
              elif i == 'right' :
                  turtle.right(n)
              else :
                  continue
          elif i == 'new' :
              turtle.reset()
              print("\n" * 50)
          elif i == 'penup' :
              turtle.penup()
          elif i == 'pendown' :
              turtle.pendown()
print('Control the turtle!')
turtle_interface()
```

But i also need to implement turtle.goto, turtle.write and turtle.color commands, which would need another string or integer variable. In what part of the code should i define these variables?

Comment: Your indentation is a little funky.  (`while True` should be indented).  And I'm not sure what the question is exactly. . .

Comment: @PauloScardine I believe so, it was initially tagged `[homework]`

Comment: Apologies for the indentation, i hope you can still understand the code. My question was, how can i add a turtle.color command (for example). Where should i define that 'color' variable?

Comment: @NullUserException: may I ask why the homework tag was removed?

Comment: @PauloScardine [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @NullUserException: ouch! IMHO it is very important to know if a question is homework. Bad decision...